# Powershell terminating with exit code 4294901760

Tags: visual-studio-code

Powershell keeps exiting with the message:

> "C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"
> terminated with exit code: 4294901760.

[image]

Comment: Are you able to open powershell window outside of VS Code ?

Comment: I can   open powershell window outside of VS Code b

Answer (score 1):

Check for this solution
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/troubleshoot-terminal-launch

> If you're on Windows 10 1809 (build 17763) or below, the issue is
> related to the legacy "winpty" backend. Upgrading to Windows 1903
> (build 18362) will move you onto the new "conpty" backend that is
> built by Microsoft and could fix your problem.