# Terminal Crashes millisecond after opening

Tags: c#, powershell, visual-studio-code, terminal

I'm a complete beginner in programming ,I was watching a c# tutorial and had to make a new project by running a terminal command

(windows 7 ultimate)

when i ran terminal it was blank then this appeared for a second

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDWWx.png

" Internal Windows PowerShell error. Invoking managed Windows PowerShell failed with error 80070002. "

then came this error

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0e35D.png

" C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell

terminated with exit code 4294901760 "

When i tried to open Windows Powershell.lnk it also crashed

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68961379/powershell-terminating-with-exit-code-4294901760

Comment: see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/114830

Comment: Also Windows 7 is end-of-life'd and has not been updated for over two years. I strongly suggest you upgrade immediately